# Discord JDA - Sometimes working, sometimes not

Tags: discord, bots, discord-jda

**What i am trying to do is :**

**When a guy leave a specific voicechannel, and this channel is now empty, the bot :**

- delete all the messages but 1 in a specific textchannel
- delete the voicechannel he just left

**The problem :**

- the voicechannel is successfully delete, but the messages in the textchannel are not delete by the bot

**The code :**

```
@Override
public void onGuildVoiceUpdate(GuildVoiceUpdateEvent event) {
     
    
      VoiceChannel channelLeft = event.getChannelLeft();
                
        if (channelLeft.getName().startsWith(" Coaching de")) { 
            
            if (channelLeft.getMembers().isEmpty()) { 
  
                channelLeft.delete().queue(); //The bot delete de channel successfully
                
                List<Message> messagesCoaching = event.getChannelLeft().getGuild().getTextChannelById("489420943991635988").getHistory().retrievePast(20).complete(); // Using a list to store the retrieved messages
        
                messagesCoaching.removeIf(m -> m.getId().equals("490567304971812885")); // Removing from the list the message i want to keep 
        
                event.getChannelLeft().getGuild().getTextChannelById("489420943991635988").deleteMessages(messagesCoaching).complete(); // Deleting all the messages (not working)
            
            } 
            
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your error is, but I'll assure you're trying to delete **all** messages sent in the text channel.

Currently, your code gets the last 20 messages from the text channel that you got by an ID. If you have more then 20 messages, the bot won't delete those. And if the messages are older then 2 weeks, it won't delete them either. Furthermore **do not use complete()** as this will stop the main thread of the bot. I'd suggest using code like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void onGuildVoiceUpdate(GuildVoiceUpdateEvent event) {
        VoiceChannel channelLeft = event.getChannelLeft();

        if (channelLeft.getName().startsWith(" Coaching de")) {

            if (channelLeft.getMembers().isEmpty()) {
                channelLeft.delete().queue(); // Telling the bot to delete the channel.
                MessageHistory history = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("489420943991635988").getHistory(); // Pulling up the history from a text channel

                history.retrievePast(100).queue(messages -> { // Putting the past 100 messages in a queue, and using a lamba to do something with the returned messages
                    messages.removeIf(m -> m.getId().equals("490567304971812885")); // If a message contains the same ID as told here, it removes it.
                    event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("489420943991635988").deleteMessages(messages).queue(); // And now, delete all messages.
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit better because it uses the queue mechanic to prevent stopping the entire bot until it has managed to do the above tasks